# If an embassy takes the passport, can they still reject the visa?

Tags: visas, italy, application-status

I had my visa interview at New York consulate for a long term Italian visa  a few days ago  and I was wondering if the visa is rejected they would  give the passport back immediately or would they send the rejection in mail?

They have collected my passport and I am still not sure if I have been approved for visa or not.

P.S. I have received my visa. :)

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE!

Comment: Hmm. but with the same logic, if they know it will be accepted, they will give you the passport quickly.  I just think they need time to get more information and to process visa (not only yours). As far I know, it is not the consulate that take the decision, they just gave information and do some preliminary work.

Comment: Applying for visas is stressful so it's always appealing to ask for reassurance. But, really, you just have to wait until you get your passport back. It shouldn't be very long.

Comment: When I was applying for my US visa, I would have know immediately if the visa is approved or denied. They would only collect your passport if they approve. But I am not sure about the Italian system.

Comment: @Morpheus even for US visas, there are certain cases where the embassy has taken the applicant's passport and the case was in administrative processing for months. So there is no guarantee that a US visa will be approved if the embassy takes your passport.

Answer (score 1):

When a consulate or embassy retains a visa applicant's passport, it may be part of its process, and not an indication of a visa decision, either positive or negative.

As with many, you may be experiencing what is referred to on this site as *post-submission anxiety*, and the [application-status](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/application-status/info) tag I added explains:

> The status of a visa application that has been submitted, but not yet returned to the applicant. Questions about application processing time, questions about how to determine the status of a given application, and questions about cancelling an application should use this tag. Include applicant's nationality, type of visa applied for, and submission date/location to help expedite an answer. Also for questions about post-submission anxiety.
>
> The visa process is especially difficult for individuals who have a low tolerance for ambiguity. These people react in different ways, some want to know the application status throughout the day and others exhibit 'post-submission-anxiety'...
>
> "post-submission anxiety" refers to an end-user state where...
>
> 1. They submitted the application without lots of planning;
> 2. Then they started surfing the net for more info;
> 3. At that point they may (or may not have) found the guidance;
> 4. They may (or may not realize) that the application has problems; and
> 5. Now they are flipping out.
>
> These questions arise from a transient condition that will be resolved when they receive the decision. There is very little anyone can do to alleviate someone's post-submission anxiety. And few people can evaluate open-ended questions like "What are my chances of refusal?" without prescient abilities anyway.

Comment: This is probably good general advice but doesn't answer the specific question: does the decision to collect the passport have any correlation with the visa being granted or refused?

Comment: @NateEldredge true, but surely no one here could possibly infer what a consulate is doing/thinking/planning, with or without the passport; it's such an open ended question and I didn't want to just VTC.

Comment: The comment by Morpheus suggested that some countries have a well-known policy of only requesting the passport if the visa is going to be approved.  If that's known to be the case for Italy, that's an answer.  If Italy is known to collect the passport regardless of the visa decision (e.g. so they can apply a "denied" stamp if necessary) then that's an answer too.

Comment: Hey guys! I got my visa. Thanks for your discussion.